# How to mount Google Bucket as local disk on Linux instance with full access rights

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, gcsfuse

Using five lines below install `gcsfuse` on a brand new Ubuntu14 instance:

```
export GCSFUSE_REPO=gcsfuse-`lsb_release -c -s`
echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt $GCSFUSE_REPO main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gcsfuse.list
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcsfuse
```

Now create a folder on a local disk (this folder is to be used as the mounting point for `Google Bucket`). Give this folder a full access:

```
sudo mkdir /home/shared 
sudo chmod 777 /home/shared
```

Using `gcsfuse` command mount Google bucket to the mounting-point folder we created earlier. But first, list the names of the Google Buckets that are linked to your Google Project:

```
gsutil ls
```

The Google Project I work on has a single bucket named "my_bucket". Knowing a bucket name I can run `gcsfuse` command that will mount `my_bucket` Bucket on to a local `/home/shared` mounting-folder:

```
gcsfuse my_bucket /home/shared
```

The execution of this command logs that it was successful:

```
Using mount point: /home/shared
Opening GCS connection...
Opening bucket...
Mounting file system...
File system has been successfully mounted.
```

But now when I try to create another folder inside of mapped `/home/shared` mounting-point folder I get the error message:

```
mkdir /home/shared/test
```

Error:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/shared/test’: Input/output error
```

Trying to fix the problem I successfully `un-mount` it using:

```
fusermount -u /home/shared
```

and map it back but now using another `gcsfuse` command-line:

```
mount -t gcsfuse -o rw,user  my_bucket /home/shared
```

But it results to the exactly same permission issue.

At very last I have made an attempt to fix this permission issue by editing `/etc/fstab` configuration file with:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

and then appending a line to the end of the file:

```
my_bucket /home/shared gcsfuse rw,noauto,user
```

but it did not help to solve this issue.

What needs to be changed to allow all the users a full access to the mapped Google Bucket so the users are able to create, delete and modify the files and folders stored on Google Bucket?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I saw your question because I was having exactly the same problem and I also did the same steps as you.
The solution to give user root full control of the mounted cloud folder :

You have to go to your Google Cloude place, search for "Service account" and clic on it.
[image]

Then you have to export the key file of your service account (.json)
(I have created a new service account with the Google Cloud Shell consol using this command : `gcloud auth application-default login`
And then followed the steps when I was prompted by the shell.)

Clic on Create Key and choose JSON
[image]
Upload the .JSON keyfile to your linux server.
Then on your Linux server, run this command : `gcsfuse -o allow_other --gid 0 --uid 0 --file-mode 777 --dir-mode 777 --key-file /path_to_your_keyFile_that_you_just_uploaded.json  nameOfYourBucket /path/to/mount`

To find your root user GID & UID, login in root to your server and in terminal type : `id -u root` for UID & `id -g root` for GID

Hope I helped, because I've been struggling for long and no resource on internet really helped. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

The answer @Keytrap gave is a correct one. But since 2017, gcsfuse as well as GCP have evolved and there are some more (maybe easier) options to let gscfuse connect with a Google account:

1. If you are running on a Google Compute Engine instance with scope storage-full configured, then Cloud Storage FUSE can use the Compute Engine built-in service account.
2. If you installed the Google Cloud SDK and ran gcloud auth application-default login, then Cloud Storage FUSE can use these credentials.
3. If you set the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to the path of a service account's JSON key file, then Cloud Storage FUSE will use these credentials.

Source: [Cloud Storage FUSE](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse)