# Not able to read files on gcsfuse mounted disk

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcsfuse

I've been able to do this before so I know it works.  In any case, I ran the command

```
sudo gcsfuse deduction3 /mnt/disks/temp_dir
Using mount point: /mnt/disks/temp_dir
Opening GCS connection...
Opening bucket...
Mounting file system...
File system has been successfully mounted.
```

I then ran

```
kylefoley@kfoley76:/mnt/disks/temp_dir$ ls
```

But nothing showed up.  There are 3 files and one folder on that storage bucket.

---

UPDATE

---

I also tried running python's `os.listdir(path)` which is what I will be ultimately using anyway. But that ended up yielding nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this from the Cloud Shell to get bucket's privacy information:

```
gsutil acl get gs://$MY_BUCKET_NAME/some_file.jpg > acl.txt
cat acl.txt
```

Comment: I got the error message `kylefoley@kfoley76:~$ gsutil acl get gs://$deduction3/hey.py
CommandException: "acl" command does not support provider-only URLs.`

Comment: To avoid this error use the name of the bucket instead of a variable (ie. gs://python-proj-bucket/hey.py , notice I took the $ out otherwise it will be interpreted as a variable ) or execute `export deduction3=real-buckets-name`

Comment: Change directory [permissions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes) to `chmod o+rx -R /mnt/disks/temp_dir3` in order to be able to get in and try again.

Comment: Thanks, I'll let you know what happens 12 hours from now.  I can't get to it now.

Comment: I'm going to see if python's `os.listdir(path)` can read the contents.  If it can then the problem is solved.  For now I'm still working on permission problems over here https://superuser.com/questions/1521031/cannot-get-access-to-directory-that-i-was-just-in-5-minutes-ago

Comment: Got the permissions problem solved but python's `os.listdir(path)` does not work and gsutil is giving the insufficient permission error even though I can enter that directory without problems.

Comment: Make sure you have the right [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/quickstart-gsutil#give_someone_access_to_your_bucket). Were you able to execute the acl command? You may check another possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42630856/how-to-mount-google-bucket-as-local-disk-on-linux-instance-with-full-access-righ?rq=1).

Comment: I solved the problem.  I had to run `sudo chmod 777 /mnt/disks/temp_dir4` before mounting the storage bucket.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake I was making was that the directory did not have sufficient permissions before I mounted it. By running `sudo chmod 777 /mnt/disks/temp_dir4` before running `gcsfuse` I solved the problem.